# Пропадает изображение при открытии другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения

Скажите я нашел такой баг, у меня есть поле для рисования `PictureBox1`... когда я открываю любую другую форму и начинаю её быстро держать по экрану(проходя через поле для рисования), у меня в том месте пропадает изображение (которое я рисовал), как можно исправить эту ошибку?

И второй вопрос, я сколько искал искал на ютубе как сохранять картинки из `Panel1` так и не нашёл...

Comment: > я сколько искал искал на ютубе как сохранять картинки

А почему на ютубе???

Comment: Ютуб, потому что на нем больше всего видео уроков...

Comment: >я сколько искал искал на ютубе как сохранять картинки
>Ютуб, потому что на нем больше всего видео уроков...

как же ошибались те несчастные, что искали материалы по программированию на башорге и сайте правительства России

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе надо рисовать на `Bitmap`'е. А потом загружать его в `PictureBox`. Вот тебе пример:

```
public class Example  
{  
    /*  ...  */   
    private Graphics graphics1;  
    private Bitmap bitmap1;  
    public Example()  
    {  
        bitmap1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);  
        graphics1 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);  
    }  
    public Draw()  
    {  
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);   
        graphics1.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, 50, 50);    
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap1;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось, теперь картинка не исчезает!

Answer (score 5):

Для начала вы должны разобраться, как работают GUI-приложения в современных ОС. Каждый раз, когда окно было кем-то затёрто или ещё по какой-нибудь причине, ОС запрашивает у приложения нарисовать затёртую область окна. Не вдаваясь в подробности, это выливается в том, что вы должны обрабатывать этот запрос. Как уже было сказано, с помощью реализации метода paint.

Что же до mouse down и сохранения. Ясное дело, что при таком подходе вы не добъётесь успеха. Вы должны либо хранить внеэкранное изображение и рисовать в него, либо хранить какую-то структуру данных в памяти, содержащую ВСЕ действия пользователя. Соответственно, будет либо растровое, либо векторное представление. При сохранении опять же вы либо растр сохраняете в виде jpg/png/etc, либо этот набор векторных объектов.

PS: И да, видеоуроки - не лучший путь. Да, просмотрев такие видеоуроки в приобретёте некие навыки и сможете что-то делать по этим шаблонам. Но эти уроки не научат вас думать и не дадут вам понимание того, как всё это работает.

Answer (score 2):

Компонент, на котором происходит рисование, скорее всего имеет метод Paint. Он вызывается, когда необходимо что либо перерисовать. Вам нужно дополнить этой метод своей логикой. То есть написать код, который будет отвечать за перерисовку содержимого.
 Насчет сохранения картинок с панели поподробнее пож.

Comment: 1. У меня рисование происходит в событии Mouse_Down, про Paint даже не знаю..
2. Ну вот кто-то нарисовал картинку в моем "Paint'e" и хочет её сохранить, как это сделать?

Comment: В Mouse_Down не надо ничего рисовать. В MouseDown нужно обновить модель, по которой Вы рисуете и вызвать Invalidate.